# Meaning of アウト in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, katakana, manga, sports

A boxer is trying to take his opponent down by brute force rather than technique. Someone frome the audience then shouts:

> アウトもカンケーねーよ！！あんなゴリ押しのタックル…！！

I think a rough translation of the sentence could be:

> What is he trying to do by tackling him down? He doesn't have to push
>   him out of the ring!

but I am not sure about the meaning of アウト. Is it a reference to some other sport? [Here you can see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlkRv.jpg) where the sentence is from. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm by no means a boxing expert, but I imagine this アウト is probably a reference to the concept of infighting versus outfighting - basically short-range versus long-range combat.

Perhaps the boxer being tackled was trying to keep his opponent at a distance ("アウト"), but the enemy's brutish tackle was so forceful that it didn't make any difference (カンケーねー)?

Comment: jp wikipedia has an article アウトボクシング which seems to confirm your hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more context, Ben's answer looks plausible, but I'd like to offer a possible alternative.

`アウト` is a term used in some sports, most notably baseball (anthonym `セーフ`), as well as tennis and golf (antonym `イン`).

The baseball meaning is also used nowadays in general speech to mean either violating some rule, especially with a possibility of punishment, or to refer to something beyond generally accepted boundaries. So I think `アウトもカンケーねーよ` could mean "It doesn't matter if it's against the rules". But I don't know if it fits the context without reading the whole chapter.